# Повторение действия при зажатой кнопке

Tags: java, android, button, listener

Написал кнопку при нажатии на которую увеличивается счетчик. Пробую написать чтобы при зажатии кнопки, счетчик рос как от множества нажатий. Но добавление слушателя приведенного ниже ломает программу и кнопка вообще реагирует на нажатие только первый раз, не говоря об увеличении числа при зажатии

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int k=0;
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        do {
            k++;
            tvSecond.setText(""+k);
            return true;
        } while(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
    return false;
}
```

. Как добиться того, чтобы при зажатии счетчик увеличивался как от множества нажатий?

Comment: не силен в Андроид, но, думаю есть кнопка типа ACTION_REALESE или unpush, ну или уж ACTION_UP. Попробуйте сделать тогда так `while(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не смог понять логику, по который вы хотели заставить работать код из примера. Внутри метода onTouch вам желаемого не добиться. Повесите поток. Это же императивная функция, вы никогда не получите в нее второй event, чтобы выйти из цикла.

Вы должны создать что-то внешнее, работающее в отдельном потоке/генерирующее таски в лупер главного потока. Из вариантов попроще - через таймер. При ACTION_DOWN запускаем таймер, который при запуске запоминает время старта и срабатывает каждый N миллисекунд. В зависимости от прошедшего времени прибавляет какое-то количество пунктов. На ACTION_UP таймер останавливаем

Comment: Спасибо, ваш совет дал именно то чего я хотел. Вкратце процесс оказался таким: 
- создать внутренний класс наследник TimerTask для описания необходимых действий(прирощения и изменения TextView). Причем эти действия необходимо выполнять в методе runOnUiThread, тк только поток создавший View может взаимодействовать с ними.
- далее в onTouch() задать как и когда Timer с необходимым TimerTask стартует и прекращается.

Comment: Вероятно написав "На ACTION_DOWN таймер останавливаем" имели ввиду  "На ACTION_UP таймер останавливаем".

Comment: Да, конечно. Поправил, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Код который при зажатии кнопки постоянно увеличивает счетчик:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new myTimerTask(), 0, 150);
        return true;
    }if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
class myTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                i++;
                tvSecond.setText(""+i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```